# Crontab, can't execute all the script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

I need to run daily a shell script which contains the steps of the model Weather Research Forecasting. I used cron for this. The first executable of the script (ungrib.exe) works perfect, but the second executable "metgrid.exe" it's not working at all. When I run the script in the terminal of linux works perfectly.

This is an example (summarized) of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash
./link_grib.csh /home/user/WRF/GFS/
./ungrib.exe
ln -s metgrid/METGRID.TBL.ARW ./METGRID.TBL
./metgrid.exe <- not running with crontab
```

The way that I configure my crontab is:

```
crontab -e

SHELL=/bin/sh

00 01 * * * /home/user/WRF/scripts/WRF_scripts.sh
```

Any idea?

Comment: All the paths prefixed with `.` are referring to the current directory. You should set the correct directory with `cd`, or use full paths. Also `#SCRIPTSDIR` is a comment, do you mean `$SCRIPTSDIR`? If so, cron jobs run in a minimal environment, so you would need to explicitly set `SCRIPTSDIR=/path/to/scriptsdir`.

Comment: Ok, but why is taking each line of the script correctly except the last one? each line runs ok, but only `./metgrid.exe` is not running. I tested by putting the whole path for that file and it's the same, it's not happening anything.

Comment: The comment was in purpouse, yes, I had to remove it from the example

Comment: What is the error message? If no error message, why do you think it is failing? Are all the programs in the user's home directory? `bash` by itself probably should not be there. If this is WSL or cygwin, watch out for problems caused by CRLF line endings in input data.

Comment: The problem was with Crontab variables. I had to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with some paths and now all works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I added in my crontab the full path of libraries related with the execution of WRF.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```